# How come the following equation produce a straight line?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, time, oscillators

[image: nature of graph from book]Time period for bar pendulum= T; 
$$T=2\pi\sqrt\frac{\frac{k^{2}}{l}+l}{g}$$
where,

*l*=distance of center of gravity(**C.G.**) from point of suspension

*k*=radius of gyration about an axis passing through the CG of the body

upon solving,

$$lT^{2}=\frac{4\pi^{2}}{g}l^{2}+\frac{4\pi^{2}}{g}k^{2}$$

and this equation produces a graph of straight line. but it was supposed to be quadratic,i guess. I checked for homogeneous equation of second degree, but it did not pass the test.

Answer (score 2):

Check the x-axis variable - it's not linear, instead it's $T^2$ and y-axis reflects this by its notation $l(T^2)$. The x-axis variable is chosen like this in order to make the dependence linear, so the coefficient of $l$ can be solved by linear fit.

Answer (score 0):

The $x$ axis variable is $l^2$ and $y$ axis variable $lT^2$.

So, your equation is similar to $y = mx+ c $, which is that of a straight line, where $m= \frac {4\pi^2} {g}$ and $c={\frac {4\pi^2} {g}}k^2$.